# Text in subscript

Tags: math-mode, boxes, subscripts

For my text-in-mathmode needs in LaTeX, I use `\mbox`. However, it does not seem to behave well in subscripts. How can I write text that adjusts its height?

```
$ 3 \mbox{dB} = f_{ 3 \mbox{dB} } $
```

compiles to

[image: example]

Comment: see the FAQ: http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=mathstext

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use the `\text` macro of the `amsmath` package instead of `\mbox` for general text in mathmode. It takes care of these issues.

Note that for *units* in math- or textmode the use of the `siunitx` package is highly recommended.

Comment: Thanks. Should I always use `\text` instead of `\mbox`?

Comment: @Tim: For text inside mathmode yes, but not in textmode.

Comment: I do not quite agree, say you want to specify the radius of a circular lake, then `$R_{\textup{lake}}$` would be a better choice. Why try setting it in an italic context. So for named indices I'd use `\textup`, one could use `\mathrm` or `\textrm`, but then what if one is using a sans serif context, so in these cases `\textup` (i.e. non italic text font) is better. But for general comments in math, `\text` is the right choice

Comment: @daleif: I didn't know about `\textup` which seems to be a nice alternative to `\text`. I was talking more about the general case in `\mbox` vs. `\text` where `\text` (or its friends) should always be used.

Comment: @martin: remember use it only when appropriate, I usually recommend it for name-like indicies, for comments `\text` is the correct thing to use. In my (Danish) LaTeX book we have an 'evil' macro such that `X_|text|` equals `X_{\textup}`. Another reason for using `\textup` over, say, `\mathrm` is that `\textup` support national letters, whereas `\mathrm` does not. Lake in Danish is `s\o{}` and `\o` is not allowed in math.

Comment: @daleif: `\textup` is also not optimal; it'll be bold in a bold context. I guess `\textnormal` is better.

Comment: @Martin: Since the question is particularly about textual subscripts, I wouldn't really recommend `\text` here.

Comment: @HendrikVogt: I thought that is exactly what `\text` is for?

Comment: @Martin: I wouldn't say so, `\text` is for text `:-)` such as `\text{if}` and `\text{otherwise}` in a `cases` environment. See also [this recent question of mine](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98406/which-command-should-i-use-for-textual-subscripts-in-math-mode).

Comment: @HendrikVogt: Well, textual subscripts are a form of text, aren't they?

Comment: @Martin: Yes, they are `:-)` But would you want the subscript to change from upright to italic, depending on the context? At least in my field that's highly undesirable!